# Setting host and port for requests.Session() objects

Tags: python, python-requests

How would I configure a `Session()` object so that all requests through it use the same host and port?

Currently I would do the following:

```
urls = [f'https://somehost.com:1234/query?page={i}' for i in range(10)]
s = requests.Session()
for url in urls:
    r = s.get(url)
```

Is there not a way to explicitly set the host and port for persistent connections? For example:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.host = 'https://somehost.com'
s.port = '1234'
```

Comment: What makes you think its not using the same host and port?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle It is not that I don't think it is, but each time I am submitting a request the host and port are part of the URL. Its explicit in the string of interest but not the object, which I thought would be better to set it that way explicitly vs implicitly. For example, if I set the host and port and then fed an incorrect URL, I could retrieve an error from that `Session`.

Comment: The `requests.Session` class doesn't take any arguments for its constructor, so you would have to specify the host/port at each request. You probably could create a simple wrapper class that lets you do so however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `requests` documentation about sessions:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the
>   Session instance, and will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if
>   you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
>   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
>   performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

So while you give the url each time. Under the hood requests will not  be creating a new TCP socket connection for each request. It will reuse the TCP socket connection to this host and port from the connection pool.

The main idea behind sessions is to share parameters and cookies between each request without having to set them individually in each request. and under the hood it will persist the connection. but you still need to give the full URL in each call

Comment: So what happens if a Session persists a connection to Host A but a URL for Host B is given to it? Does it end the persistence of Host A or do both persist?

Comment: No the TCP connection to host A will remain in the connection pool and a TCP connection to host B will be created and used and then put in the pool so now there are two connections in the pool. One to host A and one to host B.