# Should I create a separate requests.Session object for each domain I access?

Tags: python, http, session, python-requests

Assuming that in my backend I'm hitting multiple different domains/IPs, should I create a different `requests.Session` object for each domain, to avoid ever having something like this happen?

```
domain A is hit using the session, new TCP connection is created
domain A is hit using the session, the existing connection is used
domain B is hit using the session, no existing connection so a new TCP connection is created
domain A is hit using the session, it will attempt to re establish a connection with domain A
```

Based on my understanding, if I instead have two different session objects, one for domain A and B, the connection to each server should not have to be reestablished anew that way (except when the server terminates it). Something like this:

```
domain A is hit using sessionA, new TCP connection is created
domain B is hit using sessionB, new TCP connection is created
domain A is hit using sessionA, existing session's TCP connection is used
```

**Bonus question:** Should I be handling any session termination myself or should I let the requests library to handle any session termination and have it automatically reestablish a new one if needed?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597009/10035985